# React-Native Storybook crashed and spam errors

Tags: typescript, react-native, storybook

The app crashed instant after opening Storybook in the App. It spams 2 errors into console endless.

```js
 ERROR  Error: Requiring module "node_modules/core-js/internals/is-constructor.js", which threw an exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
 ERROR  TypeError: An error was thrown when attempting to render log messages via LogBox.

_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "../internals/is-constructor") is not a function. (In '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "../internals/is-constructor")(argument)', '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "../internals/is-constructor")' is undefined)
```

I am using rn `0.70.5` and `"@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.27"`

Comment: Any update on this @Antoni? I'm having the exact issue whenever I update a reducer or anything redux related. Also I'm finding shockingly nothing online about it

Comment: @discodane sadly no. I updated everything to `6.0.1-beta.10` and now it works. In my opinion, beta should be not be used for a production application, but since it is only was a feature for our development team it were fine for us

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub, but I was not able to share my code, because of some contracting things. Here the GitHub issue https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/405